# "Untwisting" line bundle on nodal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $L$ be a line bundle on a nodal curve $C$. Under which assumptions on $C$ and $L$ does there exist a "positive" Cartier divisor $D$ that "twists away" zeros of $L$ in the sense that it holds both $\mathcal{O}_C \subseteq \mathcal{O}_C(D)$ and $\mathcal{O}_C \subseteq L(D)$?

In the case of a smooth curve this is always the case as $L = \mathcal{O}_C(\sum_i m_i p_i - \sum_j n_jq_j)$ with $m_i, n_j \geq 0$ and we can choose $D= \sum_j n_jq_j$ as desired divisor. I am now interested if and if yes how I can generalize this technique if there is a twist at nodes.

Comment: Always. You can take any effective divisor $D$, then $L \subset L(D)$, because tensor product with a line bundle is exact.

Comment: I have to apology, I had a typo in my question. Of course I want $\mathcal{O}_C \subseteq L(D)$ and not $L \subseteq L(D)$, in the latter case the answer is indeed obvious. I edited my question.

Comment: Still this is always true. If $D$ is any ample Cartier divisor then both $\mathcal{O}_C(nD)$ and $L(nD)$ have a global section for $n \gg 0$, hence the required embeddings.